# Terraform always says changes on templatefile for s3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, hashicorp

I am having issues with my s3 bucket policy, it seems to add the policy correctly and even verified it in AWS and it shows the exact policy set in the policy.tpl but it keeps saying there are changes

I've tried changing the action and resource into arrays which I've heard may help.. tried removing the "Version" from the policy, the SID, keeps saying there are changes everytime i run it

policy.tf

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
  policy = local.policy
}
```

locals.tf

```
locals {
  template_dir       = "${path.module}/templates"
  template_vars      = {
    encrypt          = var.s3_require_encryption_enabled
    bucket_arn       = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn
    extra_statements = var.s3_bucket_policy
  }
  policy             = templatefile("${local.template_dir}/policy.tpl", local.template_vars)
}
```

templates/policy.tpl

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid" : "",
            "Effect" : "Deny",
            "Principal" : "*",
            "Action" : "s3:*",
            "Resource" : "${bucket_arn}/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }        
        }
    ]
  }
```

in AWS

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-us-east-1/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

says

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  #aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket" {
        bucket = "test-bucket-us-east-1"
        id     = "test-bucket-us-east-1"
      + policy = jsonencode(
            {
              + Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action    = "s3:*"
                      + Condition = {
                          + Bool = {
                              + aws:SecureTransport = "false"
                            }
                        }
                      + Effect    = "Deny"
                      + Principal = "*"
                      + Resource  = "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-us-east-1/*"
                      + Sid       = ""
                    },
                ]
              + Version   = "2008-10-17"
            }
        )
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Comment: can you run this with [TF_LOG=DEBUG](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html) and share the output if possible. As per the documentation [PutBucketPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketPolicy.html#API_PutBucketPolicy_RequestSyntax) includes `Content-MD5` which is `The MD5 hash of the request body.` calculated automatically for the requests being made via CLI or SDK. So there is definitely something being changed every time and the `md5sum` changes which trigger this change.

Comment: Nothing specific being done in the code for resource  [aws_s3_bucket_policy](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/aws/resource_aws_s3_bucket_policy.go#L53) .

Comment: thanks, after looking through logs, saw a few permissions issues, didnt have access to read bucket policy, figured it wouldnt have even ran without permissions, thanks for the tip

Comment: I added the answer based on this conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the underlying bucket policy had issues.

[PutBucketPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketPolicy.html#API_PutBucketPolicy_RequestSyntax) has

> Content-MD5
> The MD5 hash of the request body.

> For requests made using the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI) or AWS SDKs, this field is calculated automatically.)

So resource [aws_s3_bucket_policy](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/aws/resource_aws_s3_bucket_policy.go#L53) was trying to update the policy.